# spray-json for normal classes (non case) on a List

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, spray-json

I'm finding myself in a situation in which I need to serialize into JSON a non case class.

Having a class as:

```
class MyClass(val name: String) {
  def SaySomething() : String = {
    return "Saying something... "
  }
}
```

I've created a JsonProtocol for this class:

```
object MyClassJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit object MyClassJsonFormat extends JsonWriter[MyClass] {
  override def write(obj: MyClass): JsValue =
    JsObject(
      "name" -> JsString(obj.name)
    )
  }
}
```

Later on in the code I import the protocol..

```
val aListOfMyClasses = List[MyClass]() ... // lets assume that has items and not an empty list
import spray.json._
import MyClassJsonProtocol._

val json = aListOfMyClasses.toJson
```

When trying to build the project I get the following error:

**Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat for type class List[MyClass]**

spray-json has already a format for generic list and I'm providing a format for my class, what would be the problem?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I extended MyClassJsonFormat from ***JsonFormat*** instead of ***JsonWriter***, it stared working fine. Looks like the CollectionFormats trait will work only if you extend from **JsonFormat**

The following code compiles fine for me

```
  object MyClassJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

    implicit object MyClassJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[MyClass] {
    override def write(obj: MyClass): JsValue =
      JsObject(
        "name" -> JsString(obj.name)
      )

      override def read(json: JsValue): MyClass = new MyClass(json.convertTo[String])
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thks. It works, though I still don't know why CollectionFormats trait is not included. I added it to the imports explicitly but would compile ether.

Comment: No need to import CollectionFormats. DefaultJsonProtocol extends all these traits - https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/DefaultJsonProtocol.scala#L26

Comment: I know, but then it doesn't explain why it's not working when extending JsonWriter instead of JsonFormat. Is still extending DefaultJsonProtocol.

Comment: I have this same behavior - making a Writer didn't effect anything. Changing to Format does. I wonder what's going on behind the scenes - is this a bug (in spray.json)? Annoying since I also need the Reader and now I have to figure out a way to get the default reader invoked, via my format.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spray-user/HzuipsLHeYI/CmSR0V9JfD4J):

> An issue you might run into with just JsonReader/JsonWriter is that
>   when you try to lookup JsonReader/JsonWriter for Option or a
>   collection, it looks for a JsonFormat for the contained type, which
>   will fail. Not sure if there is something I am missing that will fix
>   that issue.

You and I have run into this. I don't see other way out at the moment than @user007's suggestion to use a full `JsonFormat`. That, itself, brings more difficulties at least to me - I was planning to use the default reader for my class.

Oh, well...

Comment: I would suggest you to use json4s. It will make your life way easier. At least that's what I ended up doing. No regrets at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm rather pleased with spray-json, otherwise.